# How to get step name on checkout page in magento 2?

Tags: javascript, magento, checkout, magento2

I added a custom block to "Order Summary" on checkout page. It's displaying on both steps - shipping and payment. But I need to know what is the current step. How I can get it on this block?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `Magento_Checkout/js/view/progress-bar` component or `Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator` componen (used by progress-bar) inside your custom block template/component.

Using progress-bar:

```
var registry = require('uiRegistry'),
    progressBar = registry.get('index = progressBar'),
    firstStep = progressBar.steps()[0];

progressBar.isProcessed(firstStep); // returns bool, shipping step by default
```

[image: result]

Using step-navigator:

```
var stepnav = require('Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator');
stepnav.getActiveItemIndex() // returns int - 0 for shipping & 1 for payment by default
```

or:

```
var registry = require('Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator');
registry.isProcessed('shipping'); // returns bool, you are on shipping step
```

Note: the second step name is *payment* by default

**PS:** inside your own component you can add the `Magento_Checkout/js/view/progress-bar` or `Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator` to the define list:

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
    ],
    function (
        stepNavigator
    ) {
        // do something with stepNavigator
    }
);
```

Comment: Just to clear one thing up. `isProcessed('shipping')` will return `false` on the `shipping step`, because it hasn't been processed yet. When on the `payment step` it will return `true`. Regardless thanks for this. Saved me some time :)